# Clipboard.js clipboard.copy() not working inside a Meteor callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

When I use the clipboard.copy() from clipboard.js inside of a meteor callback it brings a error that is:

```
Unable to copy. Perhaps it's not available in your browser?
```

The way that I am calling it is:

```
Meteor.call "create_course", @email, @id, (err,ret) ->
    clipboard.copy(ret)
```

The server-side create_course method works correctly and if I use the clipboard.copy("some text") outside of the callback it works as it should.

After looking at the clipboard.js file, the problem comes from the `document.execCommand("copy")` and the error comes from the execution of this part of the package:

```
try {
     console.log(document.execCommand("copy"))
     if (document.execCommand("copy")) {
        // document.execCommand is synchronous: http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-clipboard-apis-20150421/#integration-with-rich-text-editing-apis
        // So we can call resolve() back here.
            cleanup();
            resolve();
     }
     else {
        throw new Error("Unable to copy. Perhaps it's not available in your browser?");
     }
```

I want to be able to copy into the clipboard the result text that comes from the create_course callback.